# Recursive search in Mysql 5.7.30

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I need to find the list of Parent id's in which particular text exists whether it may be in parent name or in its children's name.

Consider the following table

| pid | parent | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Parent1dynamic |
| 2 | null | Parent2 |
| 3 | 1 | child1-P1 |
| 4 | 2 | Child1-P2 |
| 5 | 4 | Child-c1p2-dynamic |
| 6 | null | Parent3 |
| 7 | null | Parent4 |
| 8 | 7 | Child-p4-dynamic |

i have used the following Mysql query

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM db.tbl AS c  
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(c.parent, c.pid) AS id  
       FROM db.tbl c  
       WHERE 1=1 AND c.name LIKE '%dyna%' 
       ORDER BY c.pid ASC ) s ON s.id = c.pid 
WHERE parent IS NULL  
ORDER BY pid LIMIT 0, 15
```

Using this query im searching for text 'dyna' and getting result with ids [1 & 7], its  searching for first level
, but i need the result as [1, 2 & 7] - recursive search

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina - im using 5.7.30

Comment: If so then create iterative stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Akina for your suggestion, is it not possible without stored procedure?

Comment: *is it not possible without stored procedure?* In 5+? No.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+ it may be

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT pid, parent, name, pid rpid, pid rparent, name rname
         FROM test 
         WHERE parent IS NULL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT test.pid, test.parent, test.name, cte.pid, cte.rparent, CONCAT(cte.rname, CHAR(0), test.name)
         FROM cte
         JOIN test ON cte.pid = test.parent )
SELECT DISTINCT rparent pid
FROM cte
WHERE rname LIKE @pattern;
```

or

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT pid, parent 
         FROM test
         WHERE name LIKE @pattern
       UNION ALL
         SELECT test.pid, test.parent
         FROM cte
         JOIN test ON cte.parent = test.pid )
SELECT DISTINCT pid
FROM cte
WHERE parent IS NULL
```

In MySQL 5+ use stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_rows_like_pattern (IN pattern VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE cte (pid INT PRIMARY KEY, parent INT)
    SELECT pid, parent 
    FROM test
    WHERE name LIKE pattern;
    WHILE ROW_COUNT() DO
        INSERT IGNORE INTO cte
        SELECT test.pid, test.parent
        FROM cte
        JOIN test ON cte.parent = test.pid;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT DISTINCT pid
    FROM cte
    WHERE parent IS NULL;
    DROP TABLE cte;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb576dc26ccaac986725d382ddbf95f8c)